# C# UWP - How do I fix the FileOpenPicker and StorageFile async error?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp, filepicker

I am learning UWP, and am more familiar with Windows.Forms.

I have two buttons to upload files through my application to the server (`btnUploadPrice` is one of the two). To get the existing location of the file and store that info, i looked up how things are different in UWP compared to the Windows.Forms style and used these Microsoft pages as a template: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker

Here is my button code:

```
private void btnUploadPrice_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //open file dialog and store name until save button pressed.
    FileOpenPicker f = new FileOpenPicker();
    StorageFile price = await f.PickSingleFileAsync();
    f.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
    f.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    if (price != null)
    {
        // Store file for future access
        Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(price);
    }
}
```

`await f.PickSingleFileAsync()` is underlined with the following error:
*The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.*

My issue is that this is almost a copy/paste from Microsoft, and it's giving me an error that doesn't make sense, because it is an Async method, it says it right in the name of the method.. PickSingleFile**Async**

What am i missing?

Comment: Literally what error is saying: "The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.". Modify your method signature to `private async void btnUploadPrice_Click` and it should be fixed.

Comment: @WashingtonA.Ramos make your answer an answer so i can upvote it. that did the trick.

also, part of my having been self-taught in programming. I assumed the method was the function call f.PickSingleFileAsync() instead of being the subroutine i'm currently working in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`await` can only be used inside an `async` method. Just change your method signature to make it async:

```
private async void btnUploadPrice_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // your code
}
```